# Loading multiple external image and js in multiple view codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

[Edited Question]

Okay, sorry for my confusing question. Actually I want to locate my image/css/js in the view folder. If I load by using `<script src="application/views/script.js" />`, 403 forbidden message is appeared. Recently I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6573951/842264. But is it safe to edit the htaccess? Thank you.

Comment: Kindly tell your problem more clearly so we can asnwer it

Comment: I am sorry for my confusing question. Actually I want to load js as an external js and that js file is in the view folder. But if we located file in the view folder, we should load that file by calling $this->view->('script.js').

But if I load it by using that call, the js will be loaded as an inline js, not as an external js. I hope it is more clear than before.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [William's Concepts Template Library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template). This works with Codeigniter 2+.

You'll need to use the `add_js` function of Template. This is discussed here:
http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html#utilities

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I want to load js that located in the view folder, I can call $this->template->add_js($this->view->('script.js'), 'embed') ?

Answer (score 0):

Well there  are two simple ways .
First Method

Creates a folder assets in ci main folder which should contain 3 folders css , images and scripts
Now go to config/constants.php and define a constant there let say JS

```
define('JS','http://localhost.com/myapp/assets/scripts');
```

And now in your view file just write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JS?>/myfile.js"></script>
```

It will be loaded.
The other method is that go to config.config.php
Change base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/task/';
$config['js'] = 'assets/js';
```

And now in controller

```
$data['js'] = $this->config->item('base_url').$this->config->item('js');
```

And now in view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $js?>/myfile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I locate my js file in the views folder, not root/main folder.

Comment: locating in view folder is not a good practice and in codeigniter you should seperate them in another folder for better arrangments. httaccess should not be changed unless it is necessary

Comment: I have located my general js in the root folder and I loaded it for every pages by using `<script src="assets/js/script.js />"`. But this js is a specific js for specific module. Thus I locate the view module (index.php in application/views/module/index.php) and js module (script.js in application/views/module/script.js) in one folder. Different module has different folder which contains different index.php and script.js. I think it is more organized for me. But thank you for answer.