# Putting /assets folder into /application in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, assets

I'm starting studying [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and, before going deeply into it, I'm considering and analysing some scenarios.

One of these is about the assets (css/js/img) folder: googling around, the main trend is to put the assets folder in the root, at the same level of /system and /application; given the case that I could have more than one application (as stated here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html), each one with its own assets folder, the most logical solution for me is to put the /assets folder INTO /application folder - this seems also more "portable"

Ok, now the question: how do I reference the assets files into my views? If /assets folder is in the root, I read around that I can reference ie. the .css file like this: `<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/style.css`
But what if the /assets folder is inside /application, since I can't use `<?=base_url()?>/application/assets/css/style.css` ?

Thanks in advance!

@Brendan: Hi Brendan, thanks for the comment; I'll explain better the "portability" starting from the issue of having more than one application (/application1, /application2, etc., that is my starting point of the answer; no problem if I've only one application, but I'm prefiguring the scenario of having more than one)

Having the /assets folder at the same level as index.php means that I could end up having many subfolders as are my applications, like /assets/application1, /assets/application2, etc.

If I'd ever have to move the applicationX folders to some other computer I should remember to move also the corresponding /assets/applicationX folder; if I'd ever rename the /applicationX to /newnameX, I should remember to rename also the /assets/applicationX to /assets/newnameX to don't get a mess

Having /assets INTO /application saves me from all these problems, that's my thinking; the idea of a helper is nice, as states this article that I just found and that seems to solve exactly the questions I'm asking: http://heybigname.com/2009/11/23/managing-assets-with-codeigniter/

Comment: see [place-images-css-js-in-views-folder-codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555416/place-images-css-js-in-views-folder-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

Define "portable".

If your CodeIgniter application is set up correctly--that is:

- `system` and `application` folders below the web root
- `$config['base_url']` is correct (full domain including protocol, i.e. `http://www.example.com`)

Then you should be placing your `assets` folder in the same directory as the front controller (`index.php`). This configuration is no less "portable" (I'd argue it is moreso) than having `assets` inside of the `application` folder. If your application directory is below the web root (it really should be), you won't be able to load assets from that folder without a "proxy" script to load the file for you. At best that would mean more load on php, at worst (in the case of a poor implementation) a security risk.

In short: `assets` really doesn't belong in `application`. The beauty of PHP/CI, however, is that you can still do it if you so desire (but `application` must be above the web root).

Also, you can pass your file paths into the `base_url()` function as so:

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); // output: http://www.example.com/assets/css/style.css ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I have written an article some time ago with some point targeting this problem. I liked the way Ruby on Rails laid out the Assets folder, and I created a setup will mimics this.

See my blog here: http://www.stefandunn.co.uk/blog/custom-codeigniter-helpers-stolen-from-ruby-on-rails/

It's the last point I made.

With this, you can refer to your asset files using simple php code:

```
javascript_tag('main.js');
image_tag('logo.png', array('class'=>'logo', 'id'=> 'logo'));
stylesheet_tag('main.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in codeigniter for set up the assets as below flow:

- application
- assets
- system

But you want:

- application > assets > css > style.css
- system

but if you want to keep the assets folder inside the application, then you've to do some extra functionality as below:
First, make sure that  you've loaded the URL helper in your controller which is:

```
$this->load->helper("url");
```

you have to first create a helper named "my_helper.php" at "application/helpers" directory with this code:

```
if ( ! function_exists('asset_url()'))
{
  function asset_url() {

    return base_url().'application/assets/';

  }
}
```

Now, you have to load this helper into your controller as below:

```
$this->load->helper("my_helper");
```

Now replace your .htaccess code at 'application/'' directory with the below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

After doing all the above functionality, you have to declare your assets in view as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>css/style.css">
```